# understanding weird setState behaviour in reactjs using useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

```
const[count,setcount]=useState(0)
function inc() {
setcount(count + 5);
setcount(count + 5);
setcount(count + 5);
setcount(count + 5);
}
return (
<div>
  <h1>{count}</h1> #output =5
  <button onClick={() => inc()}>clickme</button>
</div>
);




}
function inc() {
setcount(count=>count + 5);
setcount(count=>count + 5);
setcount(count=>count + 5);
setcount(count=>count + 5);
}
return (
<div>
  <h1>{count}</h1> #output =5
  <button onClick={() => inc()}>clickme</button>
</div>
);
}
```

When i call the first function on button click count value become 5 while in second function it becomes 20. I am unable why is this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Just because these variables are returned from a React hook, does not make them behave differently than any other JS variable. A `const` is constant; it cannot change. Consider the following example without React.

```js
function logValue(input) {
  console.log(input);
}

const value = 0;

logValue(value + 5);
logValue(value + 5);
logValue(value + 5);
```

It logs 5 every time. This is what you expect right? Because `value` is constant and will **always** be 0. You might be thinking that this isn't the same because you aren't logging, you're updating. But it really isn't different. State updater functions are not simply updating a variable like `count = 5` (hint: it would break, see below).

```js
const value = 0;

function updateValue(input) {
  value = input;
}

updateValue(value + 5);
```

Instead, it tracks what the value should be **on the next render**, and when the function component is called again, the stateful const gets assigned that new value.

So even though you call the updater function more than once, the value you are sending it to update is **always** 5.

Regarding the functional update (`setCount(count => count + 5)`), here `count` does not refer to the state const, but to the parameter `count` (the naming makes it confusing because the state variable is shadowed by the parameter). This parameter is [guaranteed to contain the most recent value of state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (to help with async limitations). This is why the second set works as expected.

Here's a more complete example with logs that show when things actually are called, and their values throughout the process:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const regularUpdate = () => {
    console.log('count before update:', count);
    setCount(count + 5);
    console.log('count after 1 update:', count);
    setCount(count + 5);
    console.log('count after 2 updates:', count);
    setCount(count + 5);
    console.log('count after 3 updates:', count);
  }
  
  const functionalUpdate = () => {
    console.log('count before update:', count);
    setCount(count => {
      console.log('count inside 1st update:', count);
      return count + 5
    });
    setCount(count => {
      console.log('count inside 2nd update:', count);
      return count + 5
    });
    setCount(count => {
      console.log('count inside 3rd update:', count);
      return count + 5
    });
    console.log('count after updates:', count);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={regularUpdate}>Run normal updates</button>
      <button onClick={functionalUpdate}>Run functional updates</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setCount(0); console.clear();}}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Its worth noting the order of the logs when running the functional updates. Notice that "count after updates" logs *before* any of the logs internal to the functional updates, and that it still holds the un-updated value.

Answer (score 0):

`setcount` is the asynchronous method so 4 `setcount`s will be executed at the same time with the initial value of the `count` (0) for the first `inc()` method. So the result will be 5 even 4 `setcount`s are executed.

For the second `inc()` method, it is using the function that will receive the previous value, and return an updated value, so result is 20 as expected.

Comment: if i have last statement setCount(count+10) it overrides the state value why ?

Comment: the result will be 10

Comment: why is this so?

Comment: `setCount(count+5); setCount(count+10);` when these 2 commands are ready to be executed, param `count` will be the same value. because setCount is the async method.

Comment: then why last setCount() value  got preference over prior setCount()?

Comment: commands will be executed with the synchronous, and setCount(count+5) will be executed a little prior to the setCount(count+10), thus setCount(count+10) will be finished a little later than setCount(count+5)