# State not changing immediately in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am changing state after calling an onChange event it is not reflecting immediately. How can I make my state change Immediately.
Here is my parent component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {One, test, test1} from './Sample/SampleData';

export const FirstUser = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(One)
    const [id, setId] = React.useState("")
    
    React.useEffect(()=> {
            onChangeId(id)
    },[id])

const onChangeId = (myId:string) => {
    setId(myId)
    switch (myId) {
        case '1':
            setData(test);
            break;
        case '2':
            setData(test1);
            break;
        default:
            setData(One);
            break;
    }
}
    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent
                firstData={One} 
                onChangeId={onChangeId} 
                secondData={data}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

And below is my ChildComponent code -

```
import React from 'react';

export const ChildComponent = ({
    firstData,
    onChangeId,
    secondData
}: NewInterface) => {
const [format, setFormat] = useState(secondData);
const onChange = (
        type: string,
        val:string
    ) => {
        
        if (type === "welcome") {
                onChangeId(val);
                setFormat(secondData);                
                console.log(secondData , "secondData")                
        }
    };
    return (
        
            <React.Fragment>                
                <AnotherChildComponent
                    onChange={onChange}
                    firstData={firstData}
                    newData={format}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
    
    );
}
```

code for AnotherChildComponent is -

```
import React from 'react';

export interface SomeInterface {
    onChange: (
        type: string,
        val:  string
    ) => void;
    
    firstData: DataInterface,
    newData: DataInterface
}

export const AnotherChildComponent = ({
    onChange,
    firstData,
    newData
}: SomeInterface) => {
    let { oneData, twoData } = firstData;
    let { thirdData } = newData;

    const translatedOneData = oneData.map(({ label, value }) => ({
        label: translateFn!(label),
        value
    }));

    const translatedTwoData = twoData.map(({ label, value }) => ({
        label: translateFn!(label),
        value
    }));

    const translatedThreeData = thirdData.map(({ label, value }) => ({
        label: translateFn!(label),
        value
    }));
console.log(newData, "newData")
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                
                    <Grid container>
                        <Select
                            options={translatedTwoData}
                            value={selectedTwoData}                         
                            onChange={(val: string) =>
                                onChange('welcome', val)
                            }
                        />
                        <SectionLabel label="Newdata" />
                        <Select
                            options={translatedThreeData}
                            value={selectThirdData}
                            onChange={(val: string) =>
                                onChange('guest', val)
                            }
                        />
                    </Grid>
                
            
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

After setting state of setFormat, When I am consoling secondData in ChildComponent then it is displaying data on second time change. It is not displaying data in first time change(immediately). Means I am getting desired secondData when I call onChangeId two times. It is not showing immediately. I have used useEffect and passed `id & data` one by one but still changes data on two times call. So can anyone help me in that?

Comment: `React.useEffect(()=> {
            onChangeId(id)
    },[id])`. this is not a good practice since you added id as a dependency and inside useEffect, you are updating the id.

Comment: @WilliamWang So how can I do this to achieve my desired result, Can you help me a bit ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: @BrianThompson I have already gone through it, but in my case it's not working.

Comment: If you followed the answer in that question then you would not expect the code you provided to work. Its just not how React or Javascript work.

Comment: Here's [another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899105/understanding-weird-setstate-behaviour-in-reactjs-using-usestate-hooks/64900092#64900092).

Answer (score 0):

You should first know that `useState` mutate callbacks are asynchronous, so your `console.log(...)` right after calling the callback will always show the old value. However, I'm pretty sure the UI updates are working fine, unless you show us the code to `AnotherChildComponent`.

Either way, your `console.log` will always output the same value as mount time since that is when it was defined.

And a `WARNING`, if you are not careful with the way you call `onChangeId` in your parent component, you might end up with a recursion.

Comment: Yes I guess you are right. Can you help me a bit in that as I am new into it.

Comment: Share code for `AnotherChildComponent` component and state expected behavior clearly.

Comment: I have added the code for `AnotherChidlComponent`. Updated my question.